# Передача T в тело метода

Tags: c#

```
public static T ToCustomClass < T > (this byte[] bytes) where T {
    var mStream = new MemoryStream();
    var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    mStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    mStream.Position = 0;
    return binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream) as T;
}
```

Как я могу передать в строку с return T из ToCustomClass <T>

Comment: что значит _передать в строку с return T из ToCustomClass <T>_?

Comment: where T : class

Answer (score 1):

Вот код, который мне подошел

```
public static T ToParameterGeneralType < T > (this byte[] bytes) {
    var mStream = new MemoryStream();
    var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    mStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    mStream.Position = 0;
    var deserialize = binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream);
    if (deserialize is T deserialize1) return deserialize1;

    return default;
}
```